# Trying to rewrite Snake - Snake eats itself

Tags: java

I got a (to me, at least) *very* strange situation.
I am trying to rewrite snake, and moving is going very well, only the snake is eating itself, although I am removing 1 segment, and adding 1 (x + 1 - 1 = x?) but the snake disappears, while the Arraylist keeps the same size (printing it).

The function to calculate the position of the snake (I think that is causing it):

```
private void move() {
    System.out.println(position.size());
    Point toAdd = position.get(position.size() - 1);
    position.remove(0);
    if(dir == 1)
        toAdd.y -= 5;
    else if(dir == 2) 
        toAdd.x -= 5;
    else if(dir == 3)
        toAdd.x += 5;
    else if(dir == 4)
        toAdd.y += 5;

    if(toAdd.x < 0) toAdd.x = 150;
    else if(toAdd.x > 150) toAdd.x = 0;

    if(toAdd.y < 0) toAdd.y = 150;
    else if(toAdd.y > 150) toAdd.y = 0;
    position.add(toAdd);
}
```

But, to make it a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Snake extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    int x,y;
    boolean horizontal;
    ArrayList<Point> position = new ArrayList<Point>();
    byte dir = 3;

    public Snake(JFrame parent) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            position.add(new Point(i*5 + 10, 10));

        parent.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                byte change = dir;
                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                        change = 4;
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                        change = 1;
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        change = 2;
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        change = 3;
                        break;
                }

                changeDirection(change);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("starting thread");
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    private void changeDirection(byte change) {
        if(change != dir && (change - 2 != dir || change + 2 != dir)) {
            dir = change;
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i != -1; i++){
            try {
                move();
                this.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("INTERRUPTED");
            }
        }
    }

    private void move() {
        System.out.println(position.size());
        Point toAdd = position.get(position.size() - 1);
        position.remove(0);
        if(dir == 1)
            toAdd.y -= 5;
        else if(dir == 2) 
            toAdd.x -= 5;
        else if(dir == 3)
            toAdd.x += 5;
        else if(dir == 4)
            toAdd.y += 5;

        if(toAdd.x < 0) toAdd.x = 150;
        else if(toAdd.x > 150) toAdd.x = 0;

        if(toAdd.y < 0) toAdd.y = 150;
        else if(toAdd.y > 150) toAdd.y = 0;
        position.add(toAdd);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0,0,150,150);
        for(Point p : position)
            g.drawRect(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snake snake;
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Snake");
        f.setSize(150, 150);
        f.add((snake = new Snake(f)));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Movement was the first thing I tried to implement, I have not yet come to collision-detection/food, that's not the question here.

My question is:

**Why is the snake shrinking while the arraylist isn't and how can I fix it, i.e. stop the snake from disappearing except for the front segment?**

Comment: @downvoter explanation please?

Comment: Could someone please explain to me why this is not a real question? The last paragraph is a very clear question, I think, it's not difficult to find it, it's not overly broad, it could just be 'too localized', but then it would be one of the many here, there are questions that are far more localized on SO.

Comment: I wouldn't call it rhetorical, nor incomplete -  I even provided an SSCCE - and it surely can be reasonably answered in it's current form, by someone who's willing to look at my code and see the undoubtedly stupid error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. This is simple!

You are changing point that is already in the list `position` and at the end you add **the same** point to this list. You end up with more and more the same (by reference) elements with same positions.

You should create new instance of `Point` and add it to the list.

```
Point lastPoint = position.get(position.size() - 1);
    Point toAdd = new Point(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
```